# Consequences of Android Market/Google Play rename for developers

Tags: android, google-play

Android Market has been renamed to "Google Play." What, if any, consequences will the rename have?

For example, will intent URIs change?

Comment: Off topic??? On the contrary, this is very on topic for Android programmers. I am glad that I found this thread, as it proved to be very helpful. +1 to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new URLs used for links are documented on the [Branding Guidelines](http://www.android.com/developers/branding.html) page. One presumes that they will continue to honor `market.android.com` links for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thank you! The link in (6) for an app's detail page is wrong, isn't it? "http://play.google.com/store/details?id=packageName" should actually be "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packageName" ...

Comment: @MarcoW.: Beats me. I haven't tried it.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, it doesn't honor direct URIs containing `market.android.com`. What used to take you **directly** to specific app, only takes you now to the Google Play's landing page.

Comment: @ateiob: That's bizarre. It's not like everyone is able to update their apps quickly to switch to new URLs.

Comment: @CommonsWare I hear you, but you can verify that yourself with market://details?id=com.example.admob.lunarlander as exemplified in [this article](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1620109). It used to take you directly to the app, now it only takes to the landing page. This is very easy to check. BTW, the `http://` links works, but only when the intent is invoking a browser, not the Market app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Mystery solved. What I described was 100% true, **but only until the next reboot**. Once I rebooted my Android phone, the direct URI started working again. Who said Linux doesn't require rebooting? :-P

Answer (score 1):

Google sent this e-mail today:

> Hello Android developer,
>
> ...
>   For users and developers, the transition to Google Play is seamless.
>   ...

I hope it really is that way. All my market links (still) work, as far as I know.

The only thing that is bad is that serious apps (e.g. my UAS control app) really do not look good in a "Play" Context.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. And users will find a new unknown app on their phone and they will think: "Google Play? Don't know what this is. Won't need it." This is especially unfavorable because Android Market was just gaining more attention and name recognition.